# .on submit function runs twice - jQuery

Tags: jquery

When I select a file below on change function runs once and call submit function twice, on localhost it is calling one time but on live its calling 2 times.

```
// On change in file input.
jQuery( document ).on( "change", 'input#file', function()
{
    // runs once.
    jQuery( 'input#submit' ).submit();
});

// Submit form.
jQuery( document ).on( "submit", 'form', function( event )
{
   // runs 2 times
}
```

**html:**

```
    <form id="upload" action="" method="post">
        <div id="drop_area" class="drop">
            <input id="file" type="file" name="files" />
            <input id="submit" class="uploadSubmit" type="submit" value="submit">
        </div>
    </form>
```

-- **EDIT** --

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rLu2axza/1/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9a03mkd8/1/ - called only once

Comment: Your logic is failing somewhere, either resulting in the change event triggering twice or the submit handler being bound to the event twice.

Comment: is it because you use `return false`?

Comment: Why are you triggering the submit event on an input? Also probably a bad idea to give any input the id or name "submit"

Comment: thanks alot @Kevin B. i removed the id and now it is working all good

Comment: I have no idea why that solved it in this case, but, Happy for you that it did.

Comment: Having an id or name of "submit" usually causes .submit() when called on a formNode to not work, it shouldn't cause a double submit as you have described.

Comment: yeah on localhost the code was working nicely. but when i put it on the live site it was calling 2 times. maybe id has something to do.

Answer (score 0):

**Worked:**

changing this:

```
<input id="submit" class="uploadSubmit" type="submit" value="submit">
```

to:

```
<input class="uploadSubmit" type="submit" value="submit">
```

and use:

```
jQuery( '.uploadSubmit' ).submit();
```